# Does a reentrant list for signal queue in a single-thread environment exist?

Tags: data-structures, threads, deadlocks

I need to handle Unix signals in a single-threaded application with the following goals:

1. Signals doesn't mask on receive (thus, the signal handler *must* be reentrant).
2. I am not allowed to lose signal data (thus, if a new signal comes before the handler of the previous returned, it also must be handled correctly).

I have the common multi-threaded primitives (spinlocks, semaphores, etc). But they doesn't seem enough, because my higher-level data structures (even a such simple as a list) aren't thread-safe.

My initial idea was the following:

1. I use a *list*, in which I store the data of the incoming signal fast,
2. and process them (call the possibily much slower running handlers) later, out of the critical section.

The main problem with that, that the list data structure isn't thread safe. If I lock it, I can't store a second signal anywhere. I can't wait until the previous handler exits, because on the second signal it is essentially suspended in a critical section.

Simply I don't have any idea, how to handle the following scenario:

1. *signal1* comes, the process suspends, and the handler of *signal1* starts
2. *signal2* comes, the handler of *signal1* suspends, and the handler of *signal2* starts
3. Handler of *signal2* returns, execution returns to the handler *signal1*
4. Handler of *signal1* returns, execution returns to the main program.

After thinking a lot on it, I have an impression, maybe my problem is unsolvable. Am I right? How do operating systems handle similar problems (for example, possibily bursting interrupts from hardware)?

Comment: Why are you unable to utilize a multithreaded solution to control access to the higher-level data structure if you have access to multithreaded primitives?

Comment: @JustAnotherSoul I won't guarantee there aren't more signals delivered at once as many threads I have. And my current app is single-threaded, but it has to handle signals very well (i.e. no signal can be lost).

Comment: What I mean is, why not just spin off a thread to add the signal data to the data structure. I.E. Signal 1 comes in, thread to add the data to the list is created. ... Signal n comes in, thread to add the data to the list is created. I'm also assuming you can't simply spin off a thread to handle each signal for some reason.

Comment: Off-topic note: your architecture *will* lose signal data: if two signals are delivered to your application at almost the same time, they will be conflated, and your process will only receive one. On-topic note: pretty much any synchronization primitive does two things — test-and-set, clear-and-mask-interrupt (a.k.a. start signal handler and mask signal), test-for-input-and-block, ...

Comment: @JustAnotherSoul Good assumption, although your solution looks fine.

Comment: @Gilles Off-topic part: [sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) has a SA_NODEFER flag which disables signal masking even if its own handler runs. Doesn't this avoid the signal conflation? On-topic part: yes, my question is how to combine them into a reentrant LIFO.

Comment: @peterh SA_NODEFER reduces the window of signal conflation, but doesn't eliminate it. I don't think you can eliminate conflation completely. If the signal is delivered twice before the process gets a time slice, the process will only see one signal. This allows the kernel to maintain a boolean flag for each signal rather than a counter. (Or rather, historically, the Unix kernel had a boolean flag, so the semantics of signals was to conflate them.) The window can be very small; to observe it, stop the process (SIGSTOP), then send two signals, then resume it and see if your handler runs twice.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks! Ok, then I can't completely avoid it for the same signum, but the problem still exists because I want to handle multiple signums. And signals with different signums won't be conflated.

Comment: At that point, you could have a data structure where each signum gets its own slot, perhaps a map would lend itself well to this. Where the key is the signal and the value is the data.

Comment: @JustAnotherSoul Yes, this is what I do. What I further don't understand: how could, for example, `malloc()` work, with its much more complicated data structures? I am sure, it wouldn't make a mistake even if I call from a deep stack of signal handlers. And if `malloc()` can work, maybe a simple LIFO shouldn't have been so complex, too.

Comment: Ah, that's getting a bit beyond the scope of CS stack exchange as far as I know, as you're moving towards a coding question. The queue idea works if your handlers handle the signals faster than they arrive on the long term, otherwise at some point your system will fail when you run out of memory to store them. You can then determine a size for the queue that allows you to buffer the maximum expected signals while the handlers drain it.

Comment: @JustAnotherSoul The essence of this question is cs (reentrant lifo). My current best idea is to use a semaphore in the signal handlers to let them know, how deep are they in the signal stack. Using the actual value of this semaphore to index a static array of pointers to the siginfo structs enables the first signal handler to handle everything the others left. The disadvantage of this solution is that the array limits the simultanously handled signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, which handles the whole problem at once. It is relatively easy. They key to the solution: *we can use the signal stack as a "to-do stack"*.

Important to remember, that although this problem is also about race condition eliminiation, its solution differs significantly from the "lock everything what you use, do your task, release everything" solutions. It is because *it is not about parallelisation*, it is about *reentrancy*. The common lock-based solutions would lead to deadlock here, because the parent (in the example) *signal1* handler will be surely suspended while the whole execution of the handler of *signal2*.

So, this is a disadvantage, but it is an advantage as well. We can *guarantee*, that *signal1* won't do anything while our *signal2* runs. We can't simply lock things, but we also don't need to do them.

So, that blocking locks are closed out, only the nonblocking locks left. What I invented, is the following C code:

```
#define STORE(a, b) __atomic_store(&(a), &(b), __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)
#define SWAP(a, b) __atomic_exchange(&(a), &(b), &(b), __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)

// action handler wrapper
void ss_wrapper(int signum, siginfo_t* siginfo, ucontext_t* ucontext) {
  // currently top element on the signal stack
  static struct ss_hit *top = NULL;

  struct ss_hit *hit = ss_hit_new(signum, siginfo, ucontext);
  struct ss_hit *bkp;

  again:

  bkp = hit;
  SWAP(top, hit);
  if (!hit) { // we got the lock, we are the master
    ss_fire(bkp);
    SWAP(top, &bkp->next); // release the lock, find out if there is new element
    if (bkp->nxt) { // there IS

      hit = bkp;
      free(bkp);
      goto again;

    } else
      free(bkp);
  } else { // we didn't got the lock, but we got the top in hit
    STORE(hit->next, bkp);
  }
}
```

As we can see, it had been very beautiful to have a separated, reentrant stack (and not list) data structure.

The main problem was to understood, that

- adding new element in the stack, AND testing if it is empty, they should be done in a single atomic operation (this is why `top` serves as both of spinlock and pointer to the top of the stack)
- similarly, removing element from the stack, and to know, if it is now empty, should be done also atomically.

I also learned from this some days of thinking, that
* constructing reentrant algorithm is *much* harder as to contrust a multithread
* the most important thing is that reentrant algos should have only *very* *few* variables to interact eachother through them, and *all* operation should be atomic on them.